# not calling onNavigationStateChange when some link is clicked in WebView

Tags: ios, webview, uiwebview, react-native

#### Environment

- react-native: 0.25.1
- Device: iOS,iPhone6 Simulator
- OS: Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.4

#### code snippet

- not calling onNavigationStateChange when some link is clicked in WebView. Here is the code snippet:

  ```
  _onNavigationStateChange(navState) {
          console.log('_onNavigationStateChangeevent:',navState);
      }
  render() {
      return(
          <WebView
              style={{
                flex:1,
                marginTop:20
              }}
              ref={WEBVIEW_REF}
              source={{uri: 'https://www.tumblr.com/explore/text'}}
              scalesPageToFit={true}
              contentInset={{bottom:44}}
              onLoadStart={this._onLoadStart.bind(this)}
              onLoad={this._onLoadEnd.bind(this)}
              onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
              onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={this._onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
              startInLoadingState={true}
              javaScriptEnabled={true}
              domStorageEnabled={true}
          />
      );
  }
  ```

### **screenshots** where appropriate

detail:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7602

**How to know the navState if the onNavigationStateChange method is not called?**

Comment: did you manage to find a workaround ?

Thanks.